# how to fix routing and module problem in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-module

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected :

[image: i Compiled with warnings]

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Please share the code of the `register.component.ts` file

Comment: Share your code please.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it may be

1. you are exporting component/module twice.
2. You have configured this component in route and also creating the instance using `selector`

Comment: export * from './home.component';

Comment: home.component.ts

Comment: please share you login component code and the module where you are importing this component